# Matlab find the maximum and minimum value for each point of series of arrays (with negative values)

Tags: matlab, matrix, max, min, data-fitting

lets say that we have the next series of arrays:

```
A = [1, 2, -2, -24];
B = [1, 4, -7, -2];
C = [3, 1, -7, -14];
D = [11, 4, -7, -1];
E = [1, 2, -3, -4];
F = [5, 14, -17, -12];
```

I would like to create two arrays,
the first will be the maximum of each column for all arrays, 
i.e.

```
Maxi = [11,14,-2 -1];
```

the second will be the minimum of each column for all arrays
i.e.

```
Mini= [1,1,-17 -24];
```

I am trying all day, using loops, with max, and abs but I cant make it work

in my problem  have a matrix (100,200), so with the above example i am trying to easily approach the problem. The ultimate goal is to get a kinda fitting of the 100 y_lines of 200 x_points. The idea is to calculate two lines (i.e. max,min), that will be the "visual" boarders of all lines (maximum and minimum values for each x). The next step will be to calculate an array of the average of these two arrays, so in the end will be a line between all lines.

any help is more than welcome!

Comment: By 100 y_lines and 200 x_pts, do you mean you have an array of 100x200 columns and you want a row vector Maxi which is 1x200 and  has the maximum of each column? (similar for Mini..)

Comment: yes, but the problem is that I have negative values (elevation above and under sea level). So, for the maximum first array: I need the maximum of the positive values and the minimum negative values, which are maximum. For the second minimum 1x200 array, I would like the minimum positive values, and maximum negative values when I have only negative (like the last two columns of the A-F arrays.

Comment: So why not use abs() function. For Maxi max(abs([A;B;C;D;E;F])) and for Mini min(abs([A;B;C;D;E;F])). 

Also your example in the question does not reflect this. By your logic, shouldn't Maxi be [11, 14, -17, -24] ?

Comment: if you try you will understand why I cant use it! max(abs([A;B;C;D;E;F])) gives [11 14 17 24] not my Maxi, and min(abs([A;B;C;D;E;F])), gives [1 1[2 1]. About your 2nd comment, not because you need to see these data as elevation above and under sea level. the maximum negative is the min -value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this?

Suppose you stack all the row vectors , namely `A,B...,F` as

```
arr=[A;B;C;D;E;F];% stack the vectors
```

And then use the `max()`, `min()` and `mean()` functions provided by `Matlab`. That is,

```
Maxi = max(arr); % Maxi is a row vector carrying the max of each column of arr

Mini = min(arr);
Meani = mean(arr);
```

You just have to stack them as shown above. But if you have 100s of row vectors, use a loop to stack them into array `arr` as shown above.

Comment: Hopefully the vectors are already stacked in an array. 100 separate vectors like this would be horrible coding.

Comment: Yes, it is working! the trick was to stack the vectors! Thank you!

Comment: Do you know other way except mean, to create a fit line (array) with Matlab function? from your experience, does it sound good the way that approach the problem?

Comment: @user1640255 
1) mean() should be fine. The bottlenecks are not the functions min(), max() or mean().

2) The time consuming part is the for-loop to stack all those row vectors into one big array. If you are able to change the code that generates the vectors A, B, .., F so that it produces the stacked array in one shot (using linear algebra and/or matlab vectorization), then you can improve your times better.

Comment: On second thought, for less and discrete data, I find median as a more robust choice to show patterns. Also read about boxplots and see if you would want something of that sort for all/some x points